# powershell very long query that needs execution

Tags: powershell

How do you read a .sql file with a long string formmatted as noted below and execute the powershell command demonstrated below. The problem is that it wants a "one line"

```
  $Q = Get-Content C:\Charms\t-sql\AdUserCreation.sql   
    $CH=Get-SqlServerData -SqlServerInstanceName "server" -DbName "mydatabase" -SqlQuery $Q
```

$SqlQuery

### The file looks like this

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
p.PersonId AS EmployeeIdentification,
Si.SiteInitials,            
LOWER((LEFT(p.FirstName,1) + p.SurName)) AS UserName,
p.FirstName,
p.SurName As Lastname,
p.SurName + ', ' + p.FirstName + ' (MSH)@DSH' AS DisplayName,
A.[Address1],
A.City,
'CA' AS CA,
A.PostalCode As ZipCode,
'%ProfilesFolder%\%USERNAME%\' AS ProfilePath, 
'DSH' AS Department,
LOWER((LEFT(p.FirstName,1) + p.SurName)) AS SamAccountName,
 (CASE WHEN charindex('-', rtrim(ltrim(p.SurName))) > 0 THEN LOWER(LEFT(rtrim(ltrim(p.FirstName)), 
                         1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(p.SurName, CHARINDEX('-', p.SurName) + 1, LEN(p.SurName))) + '@dsh.ca.gov' WHEN charindex(' ', rtrim(ltrim(p.SurName))) 
                         > 0 THEN LOWER(LEFT(ltrim(rtrim(p.FirstName)), 1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(p.SurName, CHARINDEX(' ', p.Surname) + 1, LEN(p.SurName))) 
                         + '@dsh.ca.gov' ELSE LOWER(LEFT(ltrim(rtrim(p.FirstName)), 1) + rtrim(ltrim(p.SurName))) + '@dsh.ca.gov' END) AS UserPrincipalName,
class.ClassificationNumber AS ClassCode,
class.ClassificationTitle  AS JobTitle,
p.PersonId AS EmployeeIdentification,
'Created Date : ' + CAST(GETDATE() AS varchar(100)) AS MyDescription

FROM                    dbo.Person AS p INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Staff AS s ON p.PersonId = s.PersonId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Employee AS e ON s.StaffId = e.StaffId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.EmployeePosition AS ep ON e.EmployeeId = ep.EmployeeId 


ect...
```

Comment: Whats the question exactly?

Comment: I have two suggestions:  #1) If possible, create a view.  That completely separates the script from the gross data manipulation.  #2) If (1) is not possible because you need to specify things from your script that a `WHERE` clause won't cover, use a stored procedure.

Comment: problems is that i cant create views or stored procedures but i have read access to the data.

Comment: $Q is a string array and not a string, you could just loop through the array and concatenate it into a string

Comment: @BaconBits creating a view doesn't fix the script reading the file contents incorrectly for this usage. And a view isn't always an appropriate solution in the database.

Comment: @alroc You didn't see the original question.  It was the giant query *only*.

Comment: @BaconBits that doesn't change my position on the appropriateness of using a view for this.

Comment: @alroc Yes, there are situations where you might not want to separate the data model from the data view. That's why I explicitly said "if possible" because, generally speaking, you *do* want to do that. That's why it's a major design pattern. Entire technical manuals exist detailing why it's a good idea. In my experience, most DBAs are more comfortable giving a service account access to exactly the one view they need instead of all the base tables or, worse, the whole DB. The only time this isn't done is when there are political obstacles toward doing so, rather than technical.

Comment: yes i have a political obstacle ! i will try the solution jpblank put when i get back to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a file (`c:\temp\abc.txt`)

```
AA
BB
CC
```

Using simple `Get-Content` gives

```
PS C:\Temp> $a = Get-Content C:\temp\abc.txt
PS C:\Temp> $a.GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                       
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                       
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

So you can try this :

```
PS C:\Temp> $a = Get-Content C:\temp\abc.txt -Raw
PS C:\Temp> $a.GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                       
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                       
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

or this

```
PS C:\Temp> $a = Get-Content C:\temp\abc.txt | out-string
PS C:\Temp> $a.GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                       
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                       
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Answer (score 0):

All the suggestions failed to run. I did it this way

```
$query = @"

SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM PERSON

"@



 Function Get-SqlServerData
 {
  #required paramaters
  param(
        [string]  $SqlServerInstanceName,
        [string]  $DbName,
        [string]  $SqlQuery
        )
        $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $SqlCmd        = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        $SqlAdapter    = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        $DataSet       = New-Object System.Data.DataSet

        $SqlConnection.ConnectionString ="Server = $SqlServerInstanceName ; Database = $DbName; Integrated Security = True"
        $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
        $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
        $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
        $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
        $SqlConnection.Close();
        Return $DataSet.Tables[0]  
 }


$data=Get-SqlServerData -SqlServerInstanceName "myseever" -DbName "mydatabasename" -SqlQuery $query
```